# Probability one logistic is less than another?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let's say I have two independent variables that each come from a logistic distribution; that is, their PDF is

$$f_i(x) = \frac{e^{-\frac{x-\mu_i}{s_i}}}{s_i(1+e^{-\frac{x-\mu_i}{s_i}})^2}$$

**What I want to find is** $$P(x_1 < x_2)$$

There was a similar question on this site for the Gaussian distribution which used the fact that a sum of independent Gaussians is also a Gaussian, but I don't know if I have the same guarantee here for the logistic distribution.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$P(X_1<X_2)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\frac{x_2-\mu_2}{s_2}}}{s_2\cdot \left(1+e^{-\frac{x_2-\mu_2}{s_2}}\right)^2}  \left(\int_{-\infty}^{x_2}  \frac{e^{-\frac{x_1-\mu_1}{s_1}}}{s_1\cdot \left(1+e^{-\frac{x_1-\mu_1}{s_1}}\right)^2} \, dx_1 \right) \, dx_2 $$

Also substitute $\frac{x_1-\mu_1}{s_1}$ by $u$. Similar for $\frac{x_2-\mu_2}{s_2}$

Comment: I have tried this but got stuck. However, when I tried it, I started both integrals at negative infinity. Why start at 0?

Comment: Also my u substitution was e^..., not just ... Are you sure this is the right substitution? Thanks in advance. Edit: actually all I did was use the known CDF of the logistic for the inner integral. It's the outer integral that's causing trouble

Comment: @michaelsnowden I changed the lower limit. You are on the right track. I started with the substitution I mentioned in the answer. Then I substituted $e^{-u}$ by $t$. What result do you have for the inner integral ?

Comment: I can't write it out because lack of computer, but the CDF of the logistic distribution is given here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution, so I used that

Comment: This is where I'm currently at: http://imgur.com/a/UE8Ut

Comment: Ok. Now summarize the terms and try to integrate the resulting term. You have to show what you have tried.

Comment: I can´t see the image.

Comment: Try this URL: https://i.imgur.com/vkUAmz8.jpg

Comment: The exponents is $\frac{x-\mu}{s}$ and not  $\frac{\mu-x}{s}$. But in general you did a good job. Do it again an look if you get a simpler expression.

Comment: I converted from -(x-mu) to (mu-x) in most places. I think I did them all right

Comment: I hope you´re right. Have a look at your substitution. If $u=\frac{\mu_2-x_2}{s_2}$ then $us_2=\mu_2-x_2\Rightarrow -x_2=-\mu_2+us_2 $ Then substitute $e^u$ by $t$.

Comment: Ok I think I'm getting close: https://i.imgur.com/j4ezBwE.jpg

Comment: Never mind that's wrong I forgot about s1