# Probability A>B for logistic random variables

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, probability-distributions

I'm trying to understand Glicko and similar ranking systems from first principles (the Glicko paper does not explain how things are derived or even mention the logistic distribution!).

If a random variable $X$ is logistically distributed with mean $\mu$ and scale $s$, we write $X\sim L(\mu,s)$.  The pdf for the logistic distribution is
$$f(x)=\frac{e^{-\frac{x-\mu}{s}}}{s\left(1+e^{-\frac{x-\mu}{s}}\right)^2}=\frac{1}{4s}\mathrm{sech}^2\left(\frac{x-\mu}{2s}\right)$$
and the cdf is
$$F(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-\frac{x-\mu}{s}}}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tanh}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{2s}\right).$$
We want to find $$P(A > B|A\sim L(\mu_A,s_A),B\sim L(\mu_B,s_B)).$$
$$P(A>B)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^x f_A(x)f_B(y)dydx$$
$$P=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_A(x)F_B(x)dx$$
It can be shown that if $X\sim L(\mu,s)$ then $aX+b\sim L(a\mu+b,as)$ so we can transform the problem so that one of the random variables ($A$ or $B$) has standard logistic distribution $L(0,1)$.  I have generally been working with $B$ as the standard logistic random variable and then simply referring to $\frac{\mu_A-\mu_B}{s_B}$ as $\mu$ and $\frac{s_A}{s_B}$ as $s$ (these are the adjusted parameters of $A$ after transforming so $B\sim L(0,1)$).

However, then I pretty much get stuck.  I've found a few properties that could be useful but have not been able to complete the integral.  Firstly, we have the obvious integration by parts relation
$$\int_a^b f_A(x)F_B(x)dx=\left[F_A(x)F_B(x)\right]_a^b-\int_a^b F_A(x)f_B(x)dx$$
for any endpoints $a$ and $b$, and in particular when we take these endpoints to $\pm\infty$ the non-integral term on the rhs goes to $1$.  We can also prove this by changing the double integral a bit to get another expression for $P$.  Secondly,
$$
f_A(x)=\frac{1}{4s}\mathrm{sech}^2\left(\frac{x-\mu}{2s}\right)
=\frac{1}{4s}\left(1-\mathrm{tanh}^2\left(\frac{x-\mu}{2s}\right)\right)
=\frac{1}{s}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tanh}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{2s}\right)\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tanh}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{2s}\right)\right)
=\frac{1}{s}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tanh}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{2s}\right)\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tanh}\left(\frac{-x-\mu}{2s}\right)\right)
=\frac{1}{s}F_A(x)F_A(-x).$$
I originally noticed this from the exponential forms of the functions but I think the hyperbolic forms are easier to work with.  This is more useful to apply to $B$ because $F_A(\mu_A-x)=1-F_A(\mu+x)$ but $\mu_B=0$ we get $f_B(x)=F_B(x)\left(1-F_B(x)\right)$.
This lets us simply write
$$P=1-\int_{-\infty}^\infty F_A(x)F_B(x)(1-F_B(X))dx=1-\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-x}}{\left(1+e^{-\frac{x-\mu}{s}}\right)\left(1+e^{-x}\right)^2}dx$$

Ultimately, I fear there is not a closed form solution to this.  If we consider the hyperbolic form of the integral, we have
$$P=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{8s}\mathrm{sech}^2\left(\frac{x-\mu}{2s}\right)\left(1+\mathrm{tanh}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)dx=\frac{1}{8s}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathrm{sech}^2\left(\frac{x-\mu}{2s}\right)dx+\frac{1}{8s}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathrm{sech}^2\left(\frac{x-\mu}{2s}\right)\mathrm{tanh}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)dx.$$
The first integral on the rhs is clearly solvable by substitution, but the second integral does not look solvable to me.  Even if we use the argument sum formula so that the integrand becomes a rational function in sinh/cosh of $\frac{x}{2}$ and $\frac{x}{2s}$, I can't figure out how I would proceed (unless $s$ is rational so that we can use multiple argument formulae to get everything as a rational function of sinh/cosh of $x$, but this approach is absurd).

If we instead continue from the exponential form, we get
$$P=1-\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-x}}{\left(1+e^\frac{\mu}{s}\left(e^{-x}\right)^\frac{1}{s}\right)\left(1+e^{-x}\right)^2}dx.$$
And we can substitute $u=e^{-x}$ and $du=-e^{-x}dx$, then replace $e^\frac{\mu}{s}$ with $\alpha$ and $\frac{1}{s}$ with $\beta$ to get
$$P=1-\int_0^\infty\frac{du}{\left(1+\alpha u^\beta\right)\left(1+u\right)^2}.$$

For non integral values of $\beta$, it feels like this should either have no closed form solution or involve the gamma function somehow.

Is there a closed form for $P$?

(This the same as [this old unanswered question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2308623/probability-one-logistic-is-less-than-another).)